# Shinken 2 mongo dashboard

Tags: monitoring, mongodb

I like to add widgets to my Shinken dashboard. I got a warning:

> You didn't define a WebUI module for saving user preferences like the
>   MongoDB one. You won't be able to use this page!

So I installed the mongodb module:

```
shinken install mod-mongodb
```

And added the mongodb module to my webui.cfg. After a restart of Shinken, I got the same notification.

cat /etc/shinken/modules/mongodb.cfg:

```
## Module:      Mongodb
## Loaded by:   Arbiter, WebUI
# In Arbiter: Read objects in a mongodb database (like hosts or services).
# In WebUI: Save/read user preferences.
define module {
    module_name     mongodb
    module_type     mongodb
    uri             mongodb://localhost/?safe=false
    database        shinken
    #username        username     ;optional
    #password        password     ;optional

    #replica_set                  ;Advanced option if you are running a cluster environnement
}
```

Of course Mongodb is running and accessible from localhost (without creds).

Shinken version: 2.4.3

Is the mod-mongodb module still working on Shinken 2? I couldn't find an alternative module.
Latest commit c023a12 on 5 Jun 2015
https://github.com/shinken-monitoring/mod-mongodb

Anyone experience with Shinken + Webui + Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. There's a new webui version (webui2) which you can install with shinken install webui2. This version has a builtin mongo module to save data / widget settings.